# How to use the option skip-name-resolve when using MySQLdb for Python?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, resolve

I try to connect to database in a domain from my virtual machine. 
It works on XP, but somehow does not work on Win7 and quitting with:
"OperationalError: (1042, "Can't get hostname for your address")"

Now I tried disable Firewall and stuff, but that doesn't matter anyway.
I don't need the DNS resolving, which will only slow everything down.
So I want to use the option "skip-name-resolve", but there is no my.ini
or my.cnf when using MySQLdb for Python, so how can I still use this option?

Thanks for your help
-Alex

Answer (score 37):

Add the following  line(skip-name-resolve) in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-locking
skip-name-resolve
```

And restart the mysql server

Comment: I think `skip-locking` is now `skip-external-locking`

Comment: Yes, add `skip-external-locking` and `skip-name-resolve` and you'll have a bad time.

Comment: @OrlandoLeite what do you mean?

Comment: why is that? @OrlandoLeite

Answer (score 1):

This is an option which needs to be set in the MySQL configuration file on the server. It can't be set by client APIs such as `MySQLdb`. This is because of the potential security implications.

That is, I may want to deny access from a particular hostname. With `skip-name-resolve` enabled, this won't work. (Admittedly, access control via hostname is probably not the best idea anyway.)

Comment: I used IP and still get the error if you mean this by hostname.
But MySQLdb is more then the client API it is the Server for Python. Do you know where I can make those settings then? There is no MySQL service for instance, its all in the python package.

Comment: MySQLdb is not a MySQL server, it is a client API. You still need a MySQL server to connect to.

Comment: well, this does not matter for my problem anyway, because I get this error even when using an IP.

Comment: Are you able to connect to your MySQL server with the command-line client?